# prove $\partial_x^2f + \partial_y^2 f = \partial_r^2 g+\frac{1}{r}\cdot \partial_r g + \frac{1}{r^2}\cdot \partial_\Theta^2 g$

Tags: real-analysis

Given $g(r, \Theta) = f(x(r,\Theta), y(r,\Theta))$ and $x = r \cdot \cos (\Theta)$ and $y = r \cdot \sin(\Theta)$ (so f is undetermined)

First thing I gotta clear. Is my assumption righ:  $\partial_r^2 g = 2\,\sin\Theta\,\cos\Theta\,\partial_x\partial_y\,f+\cos^2\Theta\,\partial_x^2\,f+\sin^2\Theta \partial_y^2 \,f$

Second thing: Is it accordingly correct: $\partial_\Theta^2\, g = -2\,r^2\,\cos\Theta\,\sin\Theta\,\partial_x\partial_y\,f+r^2\,\sin^2\Theta\,\partial_x^2\,f+ r^2\,\cos^2\Theta \partial_y^2 \,f$

Seems almost correct 'cos $r^2$ and $\frac{1}{r^2}$ cancel out and factoring out seems probable.

But $+ \frac{1}{r}\,\partial_r\,g = \frac{1}{r} \cdot (\cos\Theta\,\partial_x\,g+\sin\Theta\,\partial_y\,g)$ kinda destroys the entire symmetry ...

Comment: The formula for $\partial_{\Theta}^2 g$ is incorrect, you forgot to apply the product rule after the first derivative ($\sin$ and $\cos$ depend on $\Theta$!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is actually the Laplacian in two dimensions which is expressed in polar and Cartesian coordinates. You can easily find the proof, see [this](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Egustafso/s2014/3150/slides/polarlaplacian-1.pdf) and [this](http://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/GREGGJ/Math400/Section_11_3.pdf) for example. In three dimensions we have

$$\Delta f = f_{xx} + f_{yy} + f_{zz} $$
And

$$\Delta f =  \frac{1}{r} (rf_r)_{r} + \frac{1}{r^2} f_{\theta \theta} + f_{zz}$$

Which reduces to two dimensions case when $f$ doesn't depend on $z$.